# Could hear and Could have heard

Tags: modal-verbs, auxiliary-verbs

*I listened. I could hear something.* - implies that I was able to hear something.

*I listened. I could have heard something*. - means that I am not sure whether I heard something or not. But it's more likely that I did.

Is my understanding of these two examples correct?

Also consider these:

*I could have heard something from their talk, but I'm not sure if that's true*.

and

*I could hear something from their talk, but I'm not sure if that's true.*

Do they still bear the same meaning? 
1. I am not certain if I heard something, and I'm not certain if that's true.

2. I certainly heard something, but I'm not sure if that's true.

Comment: Related http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/69090/could-vs-could-have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Could* is both the past tense of *can* and a conditional modal, depending on how its used.

Your first example is the past tense of can. In the present tense, it would be:

> I am listening, and I can hear something.

Your second sentence is conditional. It doesn't really mean what you said, but rather it means that had X conditions been true, Y would be true, too.

> I *could have heard* something if they *had been speaking more loudly*.

The if-clause is the condition, and were that condition be true, than apodosis (*could have heard*) would also be true. But if the condition is not true, the apodosis is also not true. Specifically with *could*, there's the sense that the protasis, the if-clause, is not true.  So:

> I could have heard something

usually means that you did not, in fact, hear anything.

If it's still up in the air, you would use *would*:

> If they were to speak louder, I *would hear something*.

Comment: What about these: "I could have heard something" and "I might have heard something".. are they interchangeable? In my opinion, the first example is vague, isn't it? It could have a condition, and if that condition was true, something would have been possible. I just want to make sure that my understanding of these goes into right direction.

Comment: I'm confused, because I ran into [these examples](http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/could-have-should-have-would-have.html), where the "could + p.p" and "might + p.p." mean the same thing. You can find something like: "He could have stuck in traffic" and "He might have stuck in traffic", where the author expresses uncertainty in both sentences, right?